# Permission denied - nginx and uwsgi socket

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

Well I am currently trying to get my django application served using nginx and uwsgi. I am currently using a virtual environment to which uwsgi is installed. However I am currently getting a 502 bad gateway error when attempting to access the page.

The Error I am experiencing.

```
2014/02/27 14:20:48 [crit] 29947#0: *20 connect() to unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 144.136.65.176, server: domainname.com.au, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock:", host: "www.domainname.com.au"
```

This is my nginx.conf

```
    # mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock; # for a file socket
    #server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name .domainname.com.au; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/deepc/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/deepc/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/deepc/.virtualenvs/dcwebproj/dcweb/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

Here is my uwsgi.ini file

```
[uwsgi]
socket=/tmp/uwsgi.sock
chmod-socket=644
uid = www-data
gid = www-data

chdir=/home/deepc/.virtualenvs/dcwebproj/dcweb
module=dcweb.wsgi:application
pidfile=/home/deepc/.virtualenvs/dcwebproj/dcweb.pid
vacuum=true
```

From what i have read on google its a permissions problem with the www-data group and /tmp/ directory. However I am new to this and have tried to changer the permission level of the folder to no avail. Could someone point me in the right direction? Is this a permissions problem.

Also is it ok practice to put the sock file in tmp directory?

Thanks

Comment: Try to change `chmod-socket=644` to 666? I'm not sure

Comment: the reason is nginx can not access the sock file. Make sure the user group started uwsgi is same as nginx group(default www-data) so that nginx can access the sock file, then everything will be ok. `usermod -g www-data username`. hope helps

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I think you just need to change your socket file to 666(664 is ok with www-data), or remove it and run uwsgi server again.

In my uwsgi.ini:

```
chmod-socket = 664
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
```

Comment: I have set this, and also tried to use the flags on the binary (--uid www-data --gid www-data) but it seems to ignore them. Any idea why?

Comment: @Chockomonkey, did you run your uwsgi (with --uid www-data --gid www-data) in command line? It will start process with your current user only. In my project, I just followed http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Upstart.html, the init script will run my uwsgi as a server, the user on the process/socket/pid will be www-data. Please let me know if something not clear, thx.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You are right, when I run it via the command line is when it ignores the --uid and --gid flags. So at least that part makes sense now, yay! However I'm still having problems getting the Emperor to run correctly with Upstart. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243445/uwsgi-emperor-permission-denied-unless-root

Comment: you sir, are a gentleman, and a scholar. I had to add the uid/gid flags inti my uwsgi.ini file.

Comment: What a legend, thank you! What's the best way to debug such issues? It's not like nginx has complained in its logs about the lack of permissions..

Comment: @Tony, hmm, just make the linux permission (user, group) clear enough, no better way :(

Comment: command line --uid and --gid works for me when running the command with sudo. I guess the normal user simply doesn't have permissions to give another process the www-data uid.

Answer (score 40):

Wow, this problem takes me almost a whole day!

I use `uwsgi 2.0.14, nginx 1.10.1, django 1.10`

To sum up, the most important thing is to make sure **both of below two users** have `rwx` permission to `socket` file:

1. the user of `nginx`;
2. the user of `uWSGI`;

So, you can check them one by one.

---

First you can check if the web server `nginx` has permission by refreshing the url, say http://192.168.201.210:8024/morning/, without running uwsgi. If you see `/var/log/nginx/error.log` **No such file or directory**, like this:

```
2016/10/14 16:53:49 [crit] 17099#0: *19 connect() to unix:///usr/share/nginx/html/test/helloworld.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.201.140, server: belter-tuesday.com, request: "GET /morning/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///usr/share/nginx/html/test/helloworld.sock:", host: "192.168.201.210:8024"
```

Just create a file named `helloworld.sock`, and refresh the url and check log file again, if you see **Permission denied** in log file, like this:

```
2016/10/14 17:00:45 [crit] 17099#0: *22 connect() to unix:///usr/share/nginx/html/test/helloworld.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.201.140, server: belter-tuesday.com, request: "GET /morning/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///usr/share/nginx/html/test/helloworld.sock:", host: "192.168.201.210:8024"
```

It means web server `nginx` does not have all permission to read, write and execute. So you can grant permission to this file:

`sudo chmod 0777 helloworld.sock`

Then, refresh the url and check log file again, if you see **Connection refused** 
in log file, like this:

```
2016/10/14 17:09:28 [error] 17099#0: *25 connect() to unix:///usr/share/nginx/html/test/helloworld.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.201.140, server: belter-tuesday.com, request: "GET /morning/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///usr/share/nginx/html/test/helloworld.sock:", host: "192.168.201.210:8024"
```

This is a good sign, it means your web server `nginx` has the permission to use `helloworld.sock` file from now on.

---

Next to run `uwsgi` and check if the user of `uwsgi` has permission to use `helloworld.sock`. Firstly, remove the file `helloworld.sock` we have created before.

Run uwsgi: `uwsgi --socket /usr/share/nginx/html/test/helloworld.sock --wsgi-file wsgi.py`

If you see **bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 230]**, it means `uwsgi` don't have permission to bind `helloworld.sock`. This is the problem of the directory `test`, the parent directory of `helloworld.sock`.

```
sudo chmod 0777 test/
```

Now, you can run `uwsgi` successful.

But maybe you still see **502 Bad Gateway**, it's terrible, I have seen it all day. If you check `error.log` file again, you will see this again:

```
2016/10/14 17:33:00 [crit] 17099#0: *28 connect() to unix:///usr/share/nginx/html/test/helloworld.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.201.140, server: belter-tuesday.com, request: "GET /morning/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///usr/share/nginx/html/test/helloworld.sock:", host: "192.168.201.210:8024"
```

**What's wrong???**

Check the detail of `helloworld.sock` file, you can see:

```
srwxr-xr-x. 1 belter mslab       0 Oct 14 17:32 helloworld.sock
```

`uWSGI` gives this file `755` permission automatically.

You can change it by adding `--chmod-socket`:

```
uwsgi --socket /usr/share/nginx/html/test/helloworld.sock --wsgi-file wsgi.py --chmod-socket=777
```

OK! Finally, you can see:

[image: successfully see the web info]

---

**Take away message**:

1. `uwsgi_params` file's location is not important;
2. Since my `nginx` user and `uwsgi` user not same and even not at the same group, so I need to give `777` permission to `helloworld.sock` and its parent dir `test/`;
3. If you put `helloworld.sock` file in your home directory, you'll always get **Permission denied**.
4. There are two places you need to set the `socket` file path, one in nginx conf file, for me it is `helloworld_nginx.conf`; one when you run uwsgi.
5. Check SELinux

This is my `helloworld_nginx.conf` file:

```
# helloworld_nginx.conf
upstream django {
    server unix:///usr/share/nginx/html/test/helloworld.sock; # for a file socket
    # server 127.0.0.1:5902; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8024;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name .belter-tuesday.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location /morning {
        include     uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass  django;
    }
}
```

Comment: While I think 0777 is too permissive, and you should find a better way to give the correct users permission instead of opening it to all users, your explanation was very good and helped me track down the issue.

Comment: When i run uwsgi --socket /tmp/mysite.sock --wsgi-file wsgi.py it displays  !!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
error removing unix socket, unlink(): Operation not permitted [core/socket.c line 198]
bind(): Address already in use [core/socket.c line 230]

Comment: You can change a dir instead of `/tmp` for your socket file, try again.

Comment: My sock file has content **helloworld.sock: No such device or address** and my web page is unresponsive

Answer (score 12):

On CentOS, I tried all those things but still it did not work. Finally, I found this article:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-se-linux-changes-upgrading-rhel-6-6/

For a development machine, we simply run:

```
semanage permissive -a httpd_t
```

But for a real production server, I have not figured out.
You may need to try other things described in the above article.

Comment: this command solved my problem that I`ve spent my whole week for, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this, solved my problem on CentOS 7. I had to install semanage with yum install policycoreutils-python.

Answer (score 8):

This is take me a lot of time to find the problem with permissions.
And the problem is with permissions of course.
Default user is nginx.
What i did:
in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` change user:

```
user  www-data;
```

Next join your user to www-data goup:

```
usermod -a -G www-data yourusername
```

Next set uwsgi:

```
[uwsgi]
uid = yourusername
gid = www-data
chmod-socket = 660
```

And then restart nginx:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

And finaly restart uwsgi.

Answer (score 3):

I grappled with this problem for a while, and found that the `uid` and `gid` flags from my `uwsgi.ini` file were not being applied to the `.sock` file

You can test this by running uwsgi, then checking the permissions on your `.sock` file using the linux command `ls -l`.

The solution for me was to run `uwsgi` with sudo:

```
sudo uwsgi --ini mysite_uwsgi.ini
```

with the `.ini` file containing the flags:

```
chmod-socket = 664
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
```

Then the permissions on the `.sock` file were correct, and the `502 Bad Gateway` error finally vanished!

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

This issue made me crazy. My environment is centos7+nginx+uwsgi, using unix socket connection. 
The accepted answer is awesome, just add some points in there.

**ROOT USER, QUICK TEST**

First, turn off selinux, then change chmod-socket to 666, and finally start uwsgi using root.

Like this

```
setenforce 0 #turn off selinux
chmod-socket = 666
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

**OTHER USER**

If you use the other user you created to start uwsgi, make sure that the permissions of the user folder under the home folder are 755, and that the owner and the group are corresponding.

For example

```
chmod-socket = 666
usermod -a -G nginx webuser #add webuser to nginx's group
cd /home/
chmod -R 755 webuser
chown -R webuser:webuser webuser
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini --gid webuser --uid webuser
```

Answer (score 1):

Another great article for CentOS users:

https://axilleas.me/en/blog/2013/selinux-policy-for-nginx-and-gitlab-unix-socket-in-fedora-19/

Although answers are useful regarding CentOS the problem lies beneath SELinux.

I followed the entire article but what solved the issue I believed where the following commands:

```
yum install -y policycoreutils-{python,devel}
grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M nginx
semodule -i nginx.pp
usermod -a -G user nginx
chmod g+rx /home/user/
```

Please substitute user with your actual user for granting permissions. Same applies for the directory under chmod command.

Answer (score 0):

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
uid = yourusername
gid = www-data
chmod-socket = 664
```

Why? Because sometimes the app needs to read or write to the file system beyond what's accessible to the web server. I don't want to change a whole bunch of ownership and permissions just to accommodate each such situation. I'd rather have my application run as me and do what it needs to do. Setting the group as www-data and chmoding the socket to 664 allows for that group to write to it, thus providing the only necessary window of communication between the web server and the app.

Answer (score 0):

In dev mode, if using root, simply set wsgi.ini or emperor.ini as below:

```
uid=root
gid=root
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add User name to the nginx config file and it will work
**Add /etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

user user_name www-data;

Answer (score -4):

you need to uncomment

```
#server 127.0.0.1:8001;
```

from upstream block and similarly do the changes in uwsgi.ini as

```
socket = 127.0.0.1:8001
```

Comment: This will use internet socket type. OP is trying to set it up with unix socket.